# Segmented Images to LMDB for Caffe

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network, lmdb

I'm using a dataset of achitectural images to try to finetune a caffe model. This dataset consists of images in one folder, and segmentation ground-truth in another folder, stored as a png image with each colour representing a label (eg. window, wall, sky.)

I'm not sure how to convert this to the lmdb format, since most tutorials don't focus on pixel-wise labeling or labels stored as colours in a png image.

Any hints would be great!

Comment: use color indexing in png format to store the labels images as 2D index images (rather than 3D RGB images)